# Значення слова "незаангажований"?

Tags: значення-слів, етимологія

Підкажіть, будь ласка, значення слова ***"незаангажований".***

> *У наших предків, **незаангажованих** сміттям мозку.....*

В словниках значення даного прикметника не знайшла.

Comment: [посилання](https://goroh.in.ua/%D1%82%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F/%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

«Політологія: словник понять і термінів» (Рябов С. Г., К., 2001) має статтю [«Заангажованість політична»](http://subject.com.ua/political/dict/571.html), з якої можна зробити висновки про сучасне вживання цього слова, на відміну від старих значень дієслова «ангажувати» – «запрошувати на танець, наймати на роботу в театрі». Стаття наступна:

> **Заангажованість політична** (від фр. engager — наймати, запрошувати) — змушеність представника неполітичної сфери (науки, мистецтва, освіти тощо) діяти в руслі певної ідеологічної доктрини, політичного курсу або навіть обслуговувати суто партійні цілі й інтереси. Взагалі поняття "ангажемент" означає контракт, укладений з артистом або театральною трупою про здійснення вистав на певних умовах і у визначені строки.